# mkbundle crashing in MakeBundle.QueueAssembly - null reference exception

Tags: mono, mkbundle

I have been trying to bundle our [ink compiler](https://github.com/inkle/ink) using **mkbundle**. Here's how I run it:

`mkbundle --static --sdk /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current --deps inklecate.exe ink-engine-runtime.dll -o inklecate_mac`

...but I get crash with the following stack trace:

`` Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MakeBundle.QueueAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] files, System.String codebase) [0x000bc] in <984a17ca6b0b4a0286f5e4481cb18cc8>:0 
  at MakeBundle.QueueAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] files, System.String codebase) [0x000bc] in <984a17ca6b0b4a0286f5e4481cb18cc8>:0 
  at MakeBundle.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00d5f] in <984a17ca6b0b4a0286f5e4481cb18cc8>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MakeBundle.QueueAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] files, System.String codebase) [0x000bc] in <984a17ca6b0b4a0286f5e4481cb18cc8>:0 
  at MakeBundle.QueueAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] files, System.String codebase) [0x000bc] in <984a17ca6b0b4a0286f5e4481cb18cc8>:0 
  at MakeBundle.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00d5f] in <984a17ca6b0b4a0286f5e4481cb18cc8>:0 ``

It used to work fine... perhaps it's broken since I updated mono a little while back? I'm currently on version **5.2.0.224**.

(If you want to reproduce on Mac, you should be able to grab the git repo I linked above, and run the `build_for_inky.command` script.)

Comment: Note that after rolling back to mono 4.8.1 it seems to work fine. Have logged a bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60125.